# Compress / Decompress Data in TStringWriter

Tags: json, delphi

I'm creating a JSON file in Delphi 10.2.3  using the `TStringWriter` and `TJSONTextWriter` classes. The resulting JSON string is quite large (50 mb). What's the most elegant way to compress the TStringWriter output and save it to a file? Clearly I'll also need to do the reverse when opening the file.

Comment: Once you compress it, it will no longer be JSON that can be immediately consumed by another tool. There's binary JSON. If you don't need other tools to consume directly any compression will do. There are lots of different ways to compress files. Choose one and find a Delphi implementation.

Comment: you can use TalJsonDocument from https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe and store the file in BSON instead of JSON (bson = binary json). Other option is to keep your file large, but read it with SAX mode (TalJsonDocument can do this also)

Comment: Of course you could always use any standard archive / compression type, e.g. gzip. I would then save the created file as .json.gz so it's obvious that it needs to be decompressed before reading. If that's an option depends on who else is reading those files.

Comment: Again: Why was this question downvoted? The downvoter did not even bother to leave a comment why he did that. I think it is a valid and well posed question.

Comment: @dummzeuch no idea. Having dug into the question it seems there isn't a standard method; I'll need to roll my own routine using the standard libraries.